# How to Turn this If Statement into a Switch

Tags: javascript

I would like to turn this if statement into a Switch but Im not sure how to go about doing it. Thanks for your help.

```js
if ((VS_WRNG !== "") && ((VS_WRNG == "DSC") || (VS_WRNG == "DSQ")) && (VS_BTYP === "")) {
    setValue('BOB_TYPE',"LIN");
    VS_BTYP = "LIN";
}
```

Comment: Why? That isn't the kind of logic that `switch` is useful for expressing.

Comment: There's no need for `VS_WRNG !== ""`. It can't be equal to the other strings if it's empty.

Comment: You can eliminate the logic before the first `&&` because it's redundant with the second part. I don't think you can really make it simpler than that, and I really don't see how or why you would change it to a `switch`.

Comment: I read somewhere that Switch statements compile faster than If's. So im trying to refactor some ifs to speed up loading time if I can

Comment: `if ((VS_WRNG == "DSC") || (VS_WRNG == "DSQ")) && (VS_BTYP === ""))` might be enough cleanup that you don't need a `switch` statement.

Comment: @AnthonySmith "compile faster"? What do you mean?

Comment: @AnthonySmith 1) JavaScript isn't a compiled language. 2) Unless you're calling this line thousands of times, it isn't going to make any measurable difference in load time, and micro-optimizations like this are usually dependent on the exact code involved. Beware of premature optimization, and the best way to tell if it actually makes a difference is to run your own benchmarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *must*, this would be one possible formulation:

```js
function x() {
  switch (VS_WRNG) {
    case "DSC":
    case "DSQ":
      if (VS_BTYP === "") {
        setValue('BOB_TYPE', "LIN");
        VS_BTYP = "LIN";
      }
  }
}
```